# How to hide bpopup jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

How can i hide the bpopup jquery using a button? i have an ajax response that if the data return error has failed bpopup will be called. then inside my bpopup i have a "Got it!" button when the user click it, it will just close the bpopup

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'my_url',
     type: "POST",
     success: function(data){
         if(data.error == 'failed){
            $('#popup').bPopup({
               modalClose: false,
               opacity: 0.6,
               positionStyle: 'fixed' 
            });

            //then my bpopup has a button "Got it!"
            $('.gotit').click(function(e) {
               //Code the will hide the bpopup.
            }
         }
     }
 })
```

i have tried `$('#popup).hide();` but it does not completely closed the `bpopup`.

BTW here's my popup html.

```
 <div id="popup" style="display: none; min-width: 350px;">
     <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;The Code does not match the information provided.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right gotit">Got it</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You realize the code above has an error, right? There's a missing `'` in the success function.

Comment: sorry for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

`if(data.error == 'failed){` here `'` is missed so add it and make it:-

`if(data.error == 'failed'){`

***Closing pop-up can do it in two ways***

***1.Hide the pop-up directly.***

```
$('.gotit').click(function() {

  $(this).closest('#popup').hide();//hidepop-up directly

  // also you can use $(this).parent().parent('#popup').hide();
});
```

Example:-

```js
$('.gotit').click(function() {

  $(this).closest('#popup').hide();//hidepop-up directly
  
  // also you can use $(this).parent().parent('#popup').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="display: block; min-width: 350px;"><!--changed disply:block to show you that how it will work -->
     <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;The Code does not match the information provided.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right gotit">Got it</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

***2.Trigger close button click event of pop-up (if close button code is already written and working)***

```
$('.gotit').click(function() {
  $('.b-close').click();
});
```

Example:-

```js
$('.b-close').click(function() { //if your close button code is alwready written
  $('#popup').hide();
});

$('.gotit').click(function(){
  $('.b-close').click(); // trigger close button clik event
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="display: block; min-width: 350px;"><!--changed disply:block to show you that how it will work -->
     <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;The Code does not match the information provided.</p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right gotit">Got it</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @p3ac3 glad to help you :):)